# Material angular: md-content with different colour of background

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have customization of theme in md-angular

```
$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .backgroundPalette('customPallete', {
        'default': '200',
        'hue-1': '300',
        'hue-2': '500',
        'hue-3': '700'
});
```

Where customPallete - is my own defined palette with custom colours.

Background colour '200' is succesfully applied to md-content.
But I can't add another colour of the background for some other components.
For example, I want to create another colour block with some data.
Here's code

```
<md-content class="md-hue-3">
 ... some code here ...
</md-content>
```

But background is the same, colour is '100' from default config of backgroundPalette.
Does someone know how to customize blocks with different background colours using **$mdThemingProvider** ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `md-colors` - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/NRdbyZ?editors=1010)

I have used "purple" as the background colour to illustrate the point. I could not get your "customPallete" to work.

Markup

```
<div layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="md-padding colorsdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content md-colors="{background: 'default-background-hue-3'}" style="height:100px">
  </md-content>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
  .config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
      .primaryPalette('brown')
      .accentPalette('green')
      .backgroundPalette('purple')
  });
```

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/colors
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdColors

Answer (score 2):

Another way is re-compile the needed style:

```
angular
    .module("YourModule")
    .config(($mdThemingProvider: IThemingProvider): void => {
        // hack new features in angular-material
        $mdThemingProvider.registerStyles(`
            md-content.md-THEME_NAME-theme {
                color: '{{foreground-1}}';
                background-color: '{{background-color}}';
            }
        `);
    });
```

So you will able to use all "md-hue-X" from your palette!